# Privacy invasion

Tags: discussion

Why do we tolerate this level of criminal intrusiveness on this site?

Here's what you MUST agree to to have an ID picture here: :

1. User Submissions. The Services may provide you with the ability to create, upload, distribute or post (“Submit(ting)”) data, photographs, avatars, software, graphics, profile and other information to the Servics (collectively, the “User Submissions”). By Submitting User Submissions, you acknowledge that you are publishing that User Submission, and that you may be identified publicly by your avatar and other User Submissions (e.g., in connection with your blogs, comments and/or email address) by Automattic, third party Gravatar-enabled websites (as that term in defined below), and others. **More specifically, you hereby do and shall grant to Automattic a worldwide, perpetual, irrevocable, royalty-free and fully-paid, transferable 
   (including rights to sublicense) right to perform the Services (e.g., to use, modify, reproduce, distribute, prepare derivative works of, display, perform, and otherwise fully exercise and exploit all intellectual property, publicity, and moral rights with respect to any User Submissions, and to allow others to do so**).

---

Reads like the fine print in Air Asia travel insurance where you think you are getting super cheap insurance and you are really signing away rights to your personal detail in irrevocable perpetuity: 
No thanks guys.

Or, to quote someone else here:

Morons

:-)

Comment: Where are you getting this statement?  I've found http://automattic.com/privacy/, but that has different text.  **edit:** Found it at https://en.gravatar.com/site/terms-of-service

Comment: What is criminal about it?

Comment: Sounds pretty similar to Stack Exchange as well... "You grant Stack Exchange the right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services."

Comment: So you want more privacy on an image that you're asking them to publish on the internet?

Comment: @W5VO - privacy on an image, no. It's all the perpetual rights, derivative rights, any use seen fit etc that goes with it. 100,000+ of my images (under reasonably open and well defined licence) anyone* can see [here](http://bit.ly/NZPHOTOS) . | * Except those whose governments bar access - as those of some of my friends do :-(.

Answer (score 8):

I, too, hate licenses and EULAs that sign your life away to the licensor, but this one doesn't seem particularly bad, especially compared to some I've read.  Most of the license requirements seem legitimate:

- worldwide: The gravatars are published on the internet.
- perpetual: How are they supposed to remove all copies if you decide you want to revoke the license?
- royalty-free and fully-paid: It's a free service...you can't charge them for your picture.
- transferable (including rights to sublicense): They need to transfer their rights to Stack Exchange, Inc. to get the image displayed.

as do the rights you grant them:

- use, reproduce, distribute, display: This is what you're trying to do. It wouldn't be much of a service if you could upload it but didn't allow them to display it anywhere...
- modify, prepare derivative works of: Resize the images so it appears in your profile and user card
- otherwise fully exercise and exploit all intellectual property, publicity, and moral rights: This is lawyerspeak, and I am not a lawyer to know what it means.

What would you propose as a better option?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are misreading this.  The rights you give up are for the *User Submission* only, meaning in this case whatever picture you upload for your avatar.  Surely you can pick a avatar picture that you don't mind them copying and displaying publicly?  So don't use a prize photograph you plan to sell exclusive rights to later.  I'm thinking your mug shot wouldn't be in the catagory anway ;-)

Think about it from their point of view.  They need this right to protect them from you suing them for distribution of the picture, which is after all what their purpose is and why you're giving them a copy of the picture in the first place.  They can't do what you want them to do without duplicating your picture.

You can always use a photo that doesn't have privacy issues attached.  Here are a few possibilities, with none of the subjects in a position to object. Of course I may have missed the mark a bit on what you would like to convey :-)

[image] [image] [image] [image]